# [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Invalid cursor state on HP -UX

Tags: odbc, hp-ux

I am using open source ODBC driver manager with our driver and i am getting this error 
24000(0)[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Invalid cursor state
I tried to debug in my driver but no help there.
Please can you explain me is this error is coming from driver manager or from mine driver.

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from the driver manager. You will be calling ODBC functions out of sequence. Turn on driver manager tracing, in your odbcinst.ini add

```
[ODBC]
Trace = Yes
TraceFile = /tmp/sql.log
```

Then run your app and see what lead up to the error.

Comment: But Same program run perfectly fith our driver manager..is there any other thing which can effect this thing

Comment: May be the other driver manager is broken and does not trap some invalid state transitions. May be unixODBC is broken and thinks this state transition is invalid. Either way, we cannot tell until you show us the ODBC trace.

Comment: One thing. unixODBC was originally written to match the published ODBC state transitions. But I have found that Microsoft don't stick to their own docs. So over time I have removed some of the checks to allign unixODBC with the Windows driver manager. So you may find (you dont say what version your are using) a later or the 2.3.2pre build doesn't show the same problem.